# make scrollbar to jump line by line while scrolling with mouse-wheel instead of 3 lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make DOM with "overflow-y: auto;" to scroll smooth when using the mouse wheel, is there any settings for CSS or JS code that would make it to scroll smooth instead of making big jump per scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible but you can use a scroll plugin to set steps on mouse wheel like [this plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Custom-Scrollbar-Plugin-malihu.html) (it needs jQuery)(you can find more documentation of it by searching the plugin name).

I hope it helps :)